# Display ItemsControl in rows and columns

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have the following XAML which displays four buttons in a single row horizontally.

How can I make it display three buttons per row and as many rows as needed?

#### XAML

```
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DataButtons}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Margin="20"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Width="100" Height="100"
                    Content="{Binding ButtonName}" 
                    Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding FilePath}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

#### What I'm getting now

[image]

#### What I need

[image]

Comment: use WrapPanel instead of StackPanel. or UniformGrid with fixed number of Columns

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot!

Comment: Man thanks to your question I was able to display the items in one row, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want to use is a `UniformGrid` like 'ASh' mentioned, it will allow you to set the `Columns` to 3 and will automatically scale the amount of `Rows` based on how many items are in the `ItemsSource`. I find this a lot easier to use than manually stacking WrapPanels.

Comment: I changed `StackPanel` to `UniformGrid Column"3"` but I like the behavior on the `StackPanel` more, the buttons overlap when the window is too small when using `UniformGrid`. Thanks